# Html quick encapsulation of text in tags

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, shortcut

Let's say i have this code: `<p>Hi Tom</p>` and I want to make Tom bold like this: `<p>Hi <b>Tom</b></p>` is there any shortcut or something in vscode to do it quickly?
Like with brackets you just select text and press bracket key on keyboard and its encapsulated.(Tom)

Comment: Give a keybinding to the command: `Emmet: Wrap with Abbreviation`

Comment: (removed [fakeiteasy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fakeiteasy) tag, since this has nothing to do with the mocking library)

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you looking for but, :

HTML wrapper: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AymanTarig.html-wrapper

HTML/JSX Class Attribute Snippets: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alexandre-eliot.html-jsx-classes

Try these extensions.